# one-line swap without temp not working in Java?

Tags: java

I tried "swap variable in java without temp" in Java and I found something that bothers me:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
b^= a ^= b ^= a;
System.out.println(a + " vs " + b);
```

The output shows

```
2 vs 0
```

However if I separate the leftmost assignment as a individual statement:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
a ^= b ^= a;
System.out.println(a + " vs " + b);
b^=a;
System.out.println(a + " vs " + b);
```

The output is

```
2 vs 3
2 vs 1
```

Now the output is as expected.
In C++, the evaluation is ensured from right to left. What the difference, in terms of language spec, tells Java could lead such expected result?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), `x ^= y` is equivalent to `x = (x) ^ (y)` (there's also a cast in there, but if you're dealing with ints, the cast doesn't matter anyway).  So this:

```
b ^= a ^= b ^= a;
```

is equivalent to

```
    b = (b) ^ (a = (a) ^ (b = (b) ^ (a)));
//      ^^^
```

In Java, arguments to an operator are always evaluated left to right.  So the `b` that I pointed to in the above is the *original* value of `b`, since it's evaluated before the assignment to `b` in the right part of the expression.  That means the expression is *not* equivalent to

```
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
```

since the third statement uses the **new** value of `b` as the left operand to `^`.